# Egrep negation inverted

Tags: regex, grep

I am using egrep for some testing/learning purpose and I am astonished of the negation ("**^**") in classes.

Im using the following text in my **test.txt**:

```
Iraq
Qantas 
Iraqi
Iraqian
miqra
qasida
qintar
qoph
zaqqum%
```

With: **egrep 'q[^u]' test.txt** the result is:
**zaqqum%** . If I understand, my result should list all the matches where a **q** exists **and**  **not** followed by **u** . 
But as you see, I ve got the opposite. Why? (I understand that I can use egrep -v ).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your grep is working as expected. It prints `zaqqum%` because of the `qq`:

```
$ egrep  'q[^u]' a
Iraqi
Iraqian
miqra
qasida
qintar
qoph
zaqqum%
```

It is more clear if you just show the matching:

```
$ egrep -o 'q[^u]' a
qi
qi
qr
qa
qi
qo
qq
```

If you add `zaqum%`, this won't appear:

```
$ echo "zaqum%" | egrep  'q[^u]'
$
```

Comment: well if I do: egrep -o 'q[^u]' , ive got only one: qu, and not qi
qi
qr
qa
qi
qo
qq

Comment: Can you check if you have an alias set on `egrep`? Do `alias egrep` to see it.

Comment: @Olegalex you probably have control characters in your file hiding the output on the terminal. add `|cat -v` to the end of the command and see what you get.

Comment: @fedorqui , I use cygwin with egrep. There is no alias command there

Comment: @Olegalex then, try using `grep -e`, which is the same as `egrep` and maybe in your case has the expected behaviour.

Comment: @fedorqui, I've tried the alternatives. Work the opposite :).Then I've tried on a Linux server and works as expected. So, never trust Windows :)

Comment: @Olegalex I agree :) Still puzzled with the behaviour of cygwin grep!